# Query para sacar id's

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta tabla con las columnas id, name, path.

Lo que requiero es que la cadena path tome el valor del id y los sustituya por el nombre, quedando de esta manera

```
| ID | name                       | path  |   path2    
|----|----------------------------|-------|------------
|  1 | Training                   | /1    | /Training           
|  2 | 1438 - Hutsville, AL, USA  | /1/4/2| /Training/Plants/1438 - Hutsville, AL, USA
|  4 | Plant                      | /1/4  | /Training/Plants
|  5 | Corporate Quality          | /1/5  | /Training/Corporate Quality
|  6 | Orientation                | /1/5/6| /Training/Corporate Quality/Orientation
```

¿Alguna sugerencia que puedo usar?

Saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo mandas la cadena `/1/3/6`?

Comment: La mando como un string, por medio un SELECT.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el select que tienes actualmente?

Comment: Había intendo algo asi SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('/1/3/6', '/', 2) pero no me funciono, realmente soy novato en MySQL y no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Comment: No se entiende bien. ¿Quieres que te muestre las categorías cuyos ids sean 1, 3 y 6?

Comment: Asi es, Yo proporciono este string '/1/3/6' asi viene definido. Y por medio de un query que se muestre las categorias por cada id

Comment: Editare mejor mi pregunta esperando ser mas claro

Comment: el campo `path` es un conjunto de ids separado por `/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar una function para que haga todo ese proceso por ti, de esta manera:

[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/FMVQM1149)

NOTA: La funcion se puede mejorar, no uso mysql, por eso esta asi.

Saludos.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, gracias

Comment: de nada, un placer ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver haciendo un Store Procedured, aplicando un group_concat inverso, lo dejo por si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`moodle`@`%` PROCEDURE `getCategogies`()
BEGIN

DECLARE description VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE id_k INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE value TEXT;
DECLARE occurance INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE splitted_value INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, path
                                     FROM moodle.mdl_course_categories;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2(
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`value2` VARCHAR(255)

) ENGINE=Memory;

OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO id_k, value;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SET occurance = (SELECT LENGTH(value)
                             - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, '/', ''))
                             +1);

    SET description = '';
    SET i=2;
    WHILE i <= occurance DO
      SET splitted_value =
      REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '/', i),
      LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '/', i - 1)) + 1), ',', '')),'/','');

     SET description =  CONCAT(description,'/',(SELECT name FROM moodle.mdl_course_categories WHERE id = splitted_value));

      SET i = i + 1;

    END WHILE;


    INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (id_k, value,description);

  END LOOP;

  SELECT * FROM table2;

 CLOSE cur1;
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

También usando  **GROUP_CONCAT()** pero con una tabla adicional con los path.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Comparto mi prueba](http://rextester.com/PBDO76243)

```
SELECT  np.id as id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(np.idpad  order by np.idpad SEPARATOR "/") as pathpad,
        GROUP_CONCAT(n.name    order by np.idpad SEPARATOR "/") as pathunion
  FROM  tb_name n inner join tb_namepath np
    on  n.id = np.idpad 
  group by np.id 
  order by np.id
```